# jQuery .get() :Rrequest to external API - Access error : Doesn't match

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

I have already taken a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) link and cannot seem to find where my issue is even after constant debugging.

I know my `.htaccess` file works because it works for internal requests and the `ReWrite` is working as expected.

My current .htaccess code (on the API server) however is:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^API/Public /API/Public/api.php [QSA,L]
```

My PHP file headers (on the API server) are:

```
// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

}
```

However, I still get this error when I try now send a request to that API server:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.example.com/API/Public/?start=example. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'http://sendingfrom.com, *').

using this code:

```
$.get('http://www.example.com/API/Public/', { start: 'example' })
                .done(function(test){
                    alert(test);
                });
```

Could someone please offer me any help to where I have gone wrong or what I am missing? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg, I found the fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33285008/5897602).

I had to remove the whole PHP headers:

```
// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

}
```